# Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder as array

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want view data with the specific id my post.

my controller is :

```
public function profile(){
    $data = Admin::with(array(5,6));
    return view('profile')->with('data',$data);
}
```

i want view `post` in `id` '5' :

```
<div class="content-about">
    <p> {{ $data[5][post]}}  </p>
</div>
```

and the other view i will `post` in `id` '6'

```
<div class="content-about">
    <p> {{ $data[6][post]}}  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you print_r($data)?

Comment: no, but i can view data if the controller is : 
 $data = Admin::find(5);
and the views is :
{{ $data['post']}}

Comment: What i mean is can i know the result of `$data`?

Comment: $data is put the field post in my database.

Comment: Can you please do `print_r($data);exit` before return view?

Comment: i just have two field in my database there are id and post.

Comment: Can i see your view?

Comment: when my controller $data = Admin::find(5); i can using print_r($data). but there are view all id, but i want view id 5 and id 6

Comment: You have to output your `$data` in one view? or there are multiple views?

Comment: How many id's in your database?

Comment: you can see my db : http://postimg.org/image/mh42ju9l7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your query is incorrect. `Model::with([...])` is eager loading specified relations. But `Admin::with(array(5,6))` passing numeric values to the function, they are ignored as `with()` expects them to be a string naming your relations. So `with(array(5,6))` actually does nothing, simply return the query instance.

To load your `Admin` with primary key 5 and 6, you need to use `whereIn()`.

```
$data = Admin::whereIn('id', array(5,6))->get();
```

Now you have the result data set. Then you want to access the result item by primary key. The result data set `$data` is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` which support such feature via `keyBy()`.

You want to access item by primary key `id`, so here is your code should look like.

```
$data = Admin::whereIn('id', array(5,6))->get()->keyBy('id');
```

Comment: Hi thanks your comment, i was try with your code `$data = Admin::whereIn('id', array(5,6))->get()->keyBy('id');` , but i get error when i try print the data with code : {{ $data['post'] }}  .

Comment: What is the exact code of your view? This is a solution for your original question which is `{{ $data[5]['post'] }}`.

Comment: waw .. Thanks so much @PaePae

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Your data is an **Array of object**

Controller:

```
 public function profile(){
   $data = Admin::whereIn('id', [5,6])->get();
   return view('profile')->with('data',$data);
 }
```

In your view:

```
 @foreach($data as $key => $post)
      <div class="content-about">
        <p> {{$post->id}} </p>
        <p> {{$post->post}}</p>
      </div>
 @endforeach
```